# CSRF token missing or incorrect django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to send some data to a view using .ajax but I am getting the CSRF token missing or incorrect error.
I have added the @ensure_csrf_cookie decorator to the view that renders the page to make sure that there is a csrf cookie.
I am using Django 1.10.5 and jquery 3.1.1

Javascript

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

function updateWaypoints(){

  var routeArray =Array(),
  routeArray =  control.getWaypoints();
  routeArray.push({route_id:routeId});
  console.log(routeArray);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(routeArray));
  var newData = JSON.stringify(routeArray);

  $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/routes/savemaproute/',
         data: newData,
     });
}
```

the view function it is send to:

```
@login_required
def save_map_route(request):
    if request.user in route.owner_user.all():
        if request.POST:
            recieved_json_data = request.POST['data']
            route_id = request.POST['route_id']
            route = get_object_or_404(Route, pk=route_id)
            route.map_waypoints = recieved_json_data
            route.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('route:details', args=(route_new.pk,)))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^savemaproute/$', views.save_map_route, name='save_map_route'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the `csrftoken` in the data sent to the view:

```
  var routeArray =Array(),
  routeArray =  control.getWaypoints();
  routeArray.push({route_id:routeId});
  console.log(routeArray);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(routeArray));
  var newData = JSON.stringify(routeArray);
```

You have defined the `csrftoken` variable, but it is not included in your `newData`.

Your `newData` object should look like this:

```
{
    // ... your key-value pairs
    csrftoken: csrftoken
}
```